# How to combine Espresso with IdlingResource with RxJava's Subject

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso, rx-android

I have a problem with combining Google's Espresso test automation library.

In production code the following transformer to apply `Scheduler`s to `Observable` is used:

```
public SCProductionUiSchedulersTransformer() {
    schedulersTransformer = new Observable.Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Object observable) {
            return ((Observable) observable)
                    .subscribeOn(rxFactory.getIoScheduler())
                    .observeOn(rxFactory.getMainThreadScheduler());
        }
    };
}
```

In Espresso automation tests the following is used:

```
public <T> SCIdlingUiSchedulersTransformer(Context context, final CountingIdlingResource countingIdlingResource) {
    schedulersTransformer = new Observable.Transformer<T, T>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) {
            return observable
                    .subscribeOn(rxFactory.getIoScheduler())
                    .observeOn(rxFactory.getMainThreadScheduler())
                    .doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            countingIdlingResource.increment();
                        }
                    })
                    .doOnTerminate(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            countingIdlingResource.decrement();
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}
```

`CountingIdlingResource` is the regular `Espresso` one used to inform automation `Thread` that application is not idle and it has to wait for the operation to complete.

For regular `Observable` the following code works without problems.

The problem is with `Observable` of type [`Subject`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/subject). Of course it does not work, because subscription to Subject is made on `Activity` start and causes the automation `Thread` to hang.

Is there any way to align the code to make it work for `Subject`? Maybe detecting that observable is of type `Subject`?

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/kaushikgopal/b680b69953cc5a5692581f69b8c9c65c

Comment: Nope, it does not work. I works with normal `Observable`, but not with the one of `Subject` type (`PublishSubject`, `BehaviorSubject`, etc...).